# How can I cast a CLOB to INTEGER in both DB2 9.5 and 11.5?

Tags: db2

I have a column that stores XML as CLOB data, and in these XMLs I have an ID information. At first, I extracted the ID information using an REGEX expression, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT
    regexp_substr(XML_CONTENT, '(<identifier>)(.*)(<\/identifier>)', 1, 1, 'c', 2) as ID
FROM XML_TABLE w
```

Then, this query results a table with one CLOB column containing the ID information. E.g.:

### |ID (CLOB)|

|123456|
|456789|

Now that I have this information, I want to join it with another table referencia an integer PK column, and to do this I need to cast the CLOB ID to INTEGER ID. How can I do that?

I'm doing this to find differences between a DEV and PROD databases, and in this environemtn DB2 versions are different, so I need this query to compatible in DB2 9.5 and DB2 11.5.

Comment: Please, edit your question providing an example of exact CLOB value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I guess I found a good solution to this problem:

DB2 11.5 (fastest way?)

```sql
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(XML_CONTENT, '(<identifier>)(.*)(</identifier>)', 1, 1, 'c', 2) 
FROM XML_TABLE;
```

DB2 9.5

```sql
SELECT
  XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('$d//identifier/text()' PASSING XMLPARSE(DOCUMENT XML_CONTENT) AS "d") AS integer) AS ID 
FROM XML_TABLE
```

Comment: using PureXML functions like XMLQUERY will be the best solution. Using REGEX to "parse" XML is really just a hack

Answer (score 1):

The REXEXP functions were introduced in DB2 11.1. So if using Db2 9.5, you would need to use e.g. LOCATE and SUBSTR. E.g.

```
SELECT  
    SUBSTR(XML_CONTENT
    , LOCATE( '<identifier>',XML_CONTENT) + LENGTH('<identifier>')
    , LOCATE('</identifier>',XML_CONTENT) - LOCATE('<identifier>',XML_CONTENT) - LENGTH('<identifier>')
    )
FROM 
TABLE(VALUES
    'blah <identifier>Some value</identifier> blah') AS X (XML_CONTENT)
```